# How to inject Room database to all of my ViewModels as singleton using Dagger2?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

This is my code so far:

```
@Module
class AppModule(private val application: App) {

    @Provides
    fun provideApplication(): App {
        return application
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAppDatabase(application: App): AppDatabase {
        return AppDatabase.getInstance(application)
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(viewModel: MainViewModel)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: App): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

Application class:

```
    lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        log("StabilityCheck: App.onCreate() - start")
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)
        connMgr = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        checkNetworkConnected()
        initNetworkConnectivityCheck()
        //init database on app start
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(AppModule(this))
            .build()
        log("StabilityCheck: App.onCreate() - end")
    }
```

MainViewModel (extended by other ViewModels)

```
open class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(private val appComponent: AppComponent): ViewModel() {...}
```

??? what to do here? I still have to pass appComponent to ViewModelFactory inside my `Fragment`.

```
class RegistrationViewModel(): MainViewModel() { ... }
```

Now how do I access `appComponent` in all extended ViewModels as singleton?

I wanted to use `Dagger` here to try dependency injection but I don't get it how its better approach if I can simply put entire `Application` class instance into constructor of any `ViewModel` upon initialization (in Fragment for example).

Update:

I used Hilt plugin to deal with this but I'm getting error:

```
public final class AppModule {
             ^
  @InstallIn, can only be used with @DefineComponent-annotated classes, but found: [com.project.application.ApplicationComponent]
```

Code:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun inject(viewModel: MainViewModel)
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}

@HiltAndroidApp
class App : Application(){

    @Suppress("unused")
    companion object {
        private const val LOG_TAG = "My-App"
        lateinit var instance: App
            private set
        val mainHandler: Handler by lazy {
            HandlerThread("MyHandlerThread").let {
                it.start()
                Handler(it.looper)
            }
        }

        fun log(s: String) = Log.i(LOG_TAG, s)
        fun debug(s: String){ if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(LOG_TAG, s) }
        fun warn(s: String){ if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.w(LOG_TAG, s) }
        fun logLongString(s: String){
            val maxLogSize = 1000
            s.chunked(maxLogSize).forEach { log(it) }
        }

        fun showToast(c: Context, @StringRes id: Int, long: Boolean = false) = showToast(c, c.getText(id), long)
        fun showToast(c: Context, s: CharSequence, long: Boolean = false) {
            Toast.makeText(c, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    private lateinit var connMgr: ConnectivityManager
    private var _isNetworkConnected = false
    val isNetworkConnected: Boolean get(){
        checkNetworkConnected()
        return _isNetworkConnected
    }

    private fun checkNetworkConnected(){
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        _isNetworkConnected = connMgr.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnected?:false
    }

    private fun initNetworkConnectivityCheck(){
        val b = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        b.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        val nr = b.build()
        val cb = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(){
            fun checkNetworkConnectedAndNotify(){
                if(isNetworkConnected) { }
            }

            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                checkNetworkConnectedAndNotify()
            }
            override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                checkNetworkConnectedAndNotify()
            }
        }
        connMgr.registerNetworkCallback(nr, cb)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
        log("StabilityCheck: App.onCreate() - start")
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)
        connMgr = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        checkNetworkConnected()
        initNetworkConnectivityCheck()
        log("StabilityCheck: App.onCreate() - end")
    }
}

@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(): App {
        return App.instance
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAppDatabase(application: App): AppDatabase {
        return AppDatabase.getInstance(application)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to access the appComponent in all extended ViewModels, you don't need to pass the entire AppComponent to the ViewModel. Instead, you should inject the specific dependencies that the ViewModel needs.

For instance, if a ViewModel needs an instance of AppDatabase, you should inject just that, not the entire AppComponent.

Comment: Can you provide code? How do I implement it without constructor?

Comment: class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val appDatabase: AppDatabase) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(RegistrationViewModel::class.java)) {
            return RegistrationViewModel(appDatabase) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}

Comment: If you want to simplify your dagger injections on android I recommend using Hilt wrapper since it handles most of those headaches (mainly - you don't have to deal with viewmodel factories).

Comment: I'm dealing with other issues with Hilt. I will update my post with error I got.